# Describing a very long matrix by a vector of vectors, which dimension should be the largest?

Tags: c++, stl, vector

I'm writing code that uses a large matrix where the elements are a user defined class. To build this matrix, I use the following vector of vectors.

```
using namespace std;
vector< vector< userclass > > matrix = vector<vector<userclass> >(sizeX, vector<userclass>(sizeY));
```

This class, which might also be a struct, will contain a few builtins such as floats and pointers. So here's the thing: 
Let's say the matrix will have a size of 2000 in one direction, but only a size of 20 in the other, but I have total freedom to choose which one. For the best performance, which one should I make the biggest, `sizeX` or `sizeY`?

In other words: which is faster, a small vector of large vectors, or a large vector of small vectors? Is there a difference at all?

The performance optimization should be towards single random accesses.

Comment: You might want to look at boost's multidimensional array library, as it not only uses memory better but also offers you standard iteration and other niceties: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should aim for the least number of vectors possible, which means that `sizeY` should be larger than `sizeX` for best cache performance, not to mention taking up less space.

---

Of course, it depends on how you intend to use them. If you can, try to stay accessing a vector for as long as possible - `vec[i][j]` is much better than `vec[j][i]`. If you have to do `vec[j][i]` then having `sizeX` be larger may have better performance, or using 1 contiguous array.

Fastest iterating where `sizeX` > `sizeY`:

```
for(int i...)
for(int j...) {
  vec[i][j];
}
```

Comment: The way they will be used is: once created and setup (which are not time sensitive operations) the matrix is only read (never written). During run time, it is accessed one element at a time, I have no control over which element will be read, and I have no reason to assume it will be sequential. Still, following what you said, having a few big vectors gives me a better chance that the same vector will be accessed repeatedly (even if it's only 1 in 20).

Answer (score 0):

There are different things to consider here. The first of all is that you are probably better off defining your own `matrix` type that holds a single vector of data of size `sizeX*sizeY` together with operators that map the coordinates to the location of the element in the vector.
The advantage of this approach is that the memory footprint will be more compact (less memory used<sup>1</sup>) and memory will be contiguous.

As of how that mapping should be done, and considering mainly performance, it depends on the usage of the data. If you are going to iterate in a particular direction, you want to make consecutive elements in that direction take contiguous positions in memory (i.e. if you are going to iterate with an external loop over the Y and an internal loop over X, then the formula should be `pos = y * sizeX + x`.

<sup>1</sup> Assuming that the type takes 10 bytes, a vector of 2000 vectors of 20 elements takes `(2000+1)*sizeof(vector) + 2000*20*10` bytes, a vector of 20 vectors of 2000 elements will take approximately `(20+1)*sizeof(vector) + 2000*20*10` bytes, and a single vector of `2000*20` elements takes `sizeof(vector)+2000*20*10` bytes. Roughly in a 64bit platform in release with no extra debugging information, `sizeof(vector<X>) ~ 3*8` (i.e. 24 bytes), and the totals would be: `448024`, `400504` and `400024` bytes. That might not make that much of a difference, but in the first case there is an extra 10% memory in use, compared to the optimal case.